# Am I having an overfitting problem with my text classification?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, text-classification, countvectorizer

I'm doing dialect text classification with 4 dialects. I split the dataset(of size 20K) into 75% training and 25% testing. When I trained them with naive bayes, and tested on the test dataset I got 90% accuracy. But when I did validation with a new dataset of size 400 tweets, I got accuracy of 63%. Do you think that drop is caused by overfitting? If there's any other information you need please tell me.

This is my code:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
text_clf = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('clf', MultinomialNB())])

text_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

pred=text_clf.predict(validate['tweets'])

accuracy_score(validate['dialect'],pred)

0.63
```

Those are my setting for for naive bayes and countVectorizer. I didn't add any hyperparameters for naive bayes. I'm not sure what to add or it it's gonna make any noticeable difference.

this is the confusion matrix:

```
array([[150,   4,  44,   1],
       [  7,  67, 105,   3],
       [ 12,  10, 110,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=int64)
```

#### Reports

**for training**

```
                precision    recall  f1-score   support

       Egypt       0.96      0.98      0.97      4039
        Gulf       0.99      0.97      0.98      4456
      Hijazi       0.95      0.97      0.96      4905
    Maghribi       1.00      0.97      0.98      3014

   micro avg       0.97      0.97      0.97     16414
   macro avg       0.97      0.97      0.97     16414
weighted avg       0.97      0.97      0.97     16414

accuracy: 0.97
```

**for testing**

```
                 precision    recall  f1-score   support

       Egypt       0.90      0.92      0.91      1321
        Gulf       0.92      0.88      0.90      1533
      Hijazi       0.84      0.92      0.88      1603
    Maghribi       0.98      0.87      0.92      1015

   micro avg       0.90      0.90      0.90      5472
   macro avg       0.91      0.90      0.90      5472
weighted avg       0.90      0.90      0.90      5472

accuracy: 0.89
```

**for new data**

```
                 precision    recall  f1-score   support

       Egypt       0.89      0.75      0.82       199
        Gulf       0.83      0.37      0.51       182
      Hijazi       0.42      0.83      0.56       132
    Maghribi       0.00      0.00      0.00         0

   micro avg       0.64      0.64      0.64       513
   macro avg       0.53      0.49      0.47       513
weighted avg       0.75      0.64      0.64       513

accuracy: 0.63
```

**Important notes**:

1. the samples that my model fails on are new tweets from twitter.
2. The egypt, gulf and maghribi dataset were mannualy annotated.
3. The hijazi dataset were fetched from twitter using twitter API by the following conditions: geolocation, user_location and keywords(specific to hijazi dialect). I did that to reduce the noise as much as possible because those tweets aren't manually labeled.

Comment: Please provide a working code sample and some data to test it with so that people here can analyze the problem. Without knowing which algorithms you use and what your meta parameters are it is impossible to tell whether your problem is overfitting or anything else.

Comment: @sekky done, I've edited the post

Comment: Overfitting sounds like a plausible explanation, but without any details, you can only get speculations. Could you [edit] the question to provide some metrics about your test and training data and its relation to the other data you are testing against, or even just some informal account of what sort of samples your model fails on and whether they are missing from the training data?

Comment: At first make sure your test set (90% precision) doesn't have common samples with your training set. If it was right, your classification hasn't been trapped by overfitting. In my opinion, your second dataset (68%) is in different format from your first dataset. Your classifier has learned the format of your data instead of the keywords, hence it has problem to classify other kind of texts different from your training dataset.

Comment: @Arashsyh if you mean by common samples a duplicate tweets, then no. I removed all duplicates. what do you mean by format vs keywords? can you elaborate more on how to fix this format issue?

Comment: @tripleee I've edited the post. the samples that it fails on are new tweets from twitter.

Comment: @JohnSall I'm giving you just a simple example of what might happened, but you, extend it to more problems which may occured.
For example consider a situation that most of the tweets of dialects 1 are written in 3 lines but tweets of dialects 2 are written in 1 line. In this situation, your classifier instead of using keywords as features, takes lines count as feature, When you test the classifier with different dataset your classifer get confused, classifies the 3 line tweets to class 1, 1 line to class 2 and so on. In this case this is your training dataset problem which should be fixed.

Comment: @Arashsyh I've added important notes at the end, please read them.

Comment: So are the new tweets somehow different from the ones you have trained on? Topically, lexically, do they resemble stuff you have trained on, on some level? Or do you just expect a magic black box solution without any insights into whether the results you hope for are realistic?

Comment: @tripleee no, they're not different. the idea is that every dialect has specific keywords only used by that dialect. so when I train the the tweets, they catch on those keywords. and so when I test on new tweets, hopefully there would be some of those keywords present there.